# Swagger Authentication against Azure AD

Tags: azure, swagger, azure-active-directory, swagger-ui

I'm trying to enable swagger-generated UIs to be able to make authenticated calls to a Web API using Azure AD as the authentication mechanism.

I ran across two documents:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pratushb/2016/04/28/enable-swagger-to-authenticate-against-azure-ad/

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/isgupt/2017/09/04/swagger-authentication-against-azure-ad-b2c/

They both have different interfaces from each other and different interfaces from what I see when I go to Azure now. Azure is barreling along and changing significantly very frequently.

How do we do this nowadays? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm, one of those is for Azure AD in old portal, and the other is AAD B2C. Other than the new portal looking slightly different, you should be able to find the same things as the first article from the new portal.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something then. It seems to break down frequently, as far as something in the directions not existing or being reworded.

Comment: Well, if you face a specific problem, feel free to make a question :)

Comment: You can find the app registration stuff in the new portal by going to *Azure Active Directory* on the left sidebar, or by going to *More services* and finding it there.